# Some numeric labels don't show up in my Sublime Text

Tags: software-installation, gui, sublime-text

I reinstalled Sublime Text 3 multiple times but it does not show up some numbers. For example line number, column number, build number, etc. (see image below).

[image: Sublime Issue]

I don't understand what's going on but I think that it's an issue with my system rather than Sublime because even Sublime Text 2 behaves similarly.

Comment: Problems with text rendering are often caused by bugs in FreeType, so you might have to upgrade (or downgrade) your version.

Comment: Hey! I tried upgrading freetype but that didn't solve the problem. Any other ideas?